# Major Differences between Zend Framework 2 and Symfony 2

Tags: symfony, zend-framework2

I have been looking into Symfony 2 and also the new beta release of Zend Framework 2 and I am seeing a lot of similarities. Both seem to really focus on [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), and both look like they have the ability to add fully packaged "modules" with corresponding MVC components.

I am unfamiliar with both frameworks enough that I could go either way for my next project. Are there key differences between the two frameworks that should help guide my decision for picking between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start a new project now, you should start using Symfony as there is already a stable release and there are already a lot of available bundles (http://symfony2bundles.org).

Anyway, as they both follow the PSR-0, you can easily combine them. They both provide a lot of good standalone libraries.

Comment: Thanks! The bundle site is sweet!

Comment: The site http://symfony2bundles.org is now http://bundles.knplabs.org because of copyright issues.

Comment: This argument did not answer the (admittedly hard) question and is moot now that ZF2 also has a stable release.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer: Depends on the project. For me, SF is the choice because it is ideal to build large projects over years, as it gives a real project environment. Especially if you're not doing your stuff for a client.

If you just wanna get the job done grab the right zend libs and ship it. SF is when you care about the baby ;-)

Comment: I like what you say about the project environment. I am loving SF2. Bundles are awesome.

Comment: I appreciate hearing your positive comments. I am really impressed with user-friendly quality of the symfony documentation.

Comment: Johannes u prob dont know to develop in ZF2 !!! So dont blame him if u dont know....